# Como hacer funcionar el theme en mi app movil en flutter

Tags: web, flutter, dart, aplicación-movil

estoy teniendo problemas en hacer funcionar el theme de mi app, estoy viendo un curso siguiendo los pasos correspondientes pero el theme no me funciona, estoy usando el VSCODE y android studio para ejecutar el emulador de movil, ahora adjunto el codigo y el problema con una imagen

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.indigo),
     home:const RootPage(),
   );
 }
}

// Raiz de nuestras paginas
class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RootPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RootPage> createState() => _RootPageState(); 
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
   );
 }
}
```

Aca adjunto la foto para que vean que no se muestra el theme en el appBar
[image: problema flutter theme]

Comment: Seguramente tengas las última versión de Flutter, que usa `useMaterial3` por defecto a true. Para evitar problemas, en el `ThemeData` busca la propiedad que te he dicho y ponla a false.